# Differences in JavaScript Static Object Creation Approaches

Tags: javascript, static, static-members, object-literal

I'm a Java developer trying to learn JavaScript ethos.

Are these two approaches for creating a static object in JavaScript different in any non-syntactical way? Which approach is more acceptable from a JavaScript programmer's perspective?

Approach A:

```
var obj = {};
obj.field1 = /* some expression */;
obj.field2 = /* some expression */;
```

Approach B:

```
var obj = {
    field1: /* some expression */,
    field2: /* some expression */
};
```

Comment: I tend to use Approach B. Approach A is nice when you need to access the object literal. For example, if you wanted to define `field2` **based on** `field1`; you can't exactly do that in the object literal initialization.

Comment: Another, similar but different in effect way is to use a `new` operator on a constructor function:
`var obj = new (function Object() {this.field1 = /* some expression */; this.field2 = /* some expression */; var privateProperty = "somevalue"; this.field3 = this.field1+privateProperty; })();` This allows you hide some properties if that's required.

Comment: Another way is to use: `Object.create` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both of the objects end up being created in a similar manner, and the difference in performance (if any) will be minute to the point where you shouldn't notice a difference.

This is not universal, though. When creating arrays, it is more efficient to use a similar approach to B. This is because (at least with V8) allocating an array with a set size is more efficient because it knows the size of the array.

```
// Here V8 can see that you want a 4-element array containing numbers:
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Don't do this:
a = []; // Here V8 knows nothing about the array
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    a.push(i);
}
```

Source: [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/)

I would suggest trying out the [Chrome Profiling Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles) to see if you can notice a difference between the efficiency of both approaches, although I think if there is a difference it will be too small to make a difference.

Further more, if you are new to JavaScript, I would suggest checking out the awesome [JavaScript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) created by AirBnB. There are a ton of great tips for writing efficient and clean JavaScript.